# Series representation for $(1+x)^{n-m}(1-x)^{m}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

As the title suggests, for $n,m$ integers such that $0\leq m \leq n$, is there a series representation for

$$f(n,m)=(1+x)^{n-m}(1-x)^{m}$$

for each $m$? Been looking online to no avail...

Comment: That is the closed form.

Comment: Sorry should have asked instead for a series representation for this...edited the above

Answer (score 0):

First note that 
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k x^\alpha=p_k(\alpha)x^{\alpha-k}$$
where $$p_k(\alpha)=\prod_{j=1}^{k}(\alpha-j+1).$$
Hence for $|x|<1$, 
$$(1-x)^\alpha=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^kp_k(\alpha)}{k!}x^k$$
and $$(1+x)^\beta=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{p_k(\beta)}{k!}x^k.$$
Hence 
$$(1+x)^\beta(1-x)^\alpha=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kp_k(\alpha)p_{n-k}(\beta)}{k!(n-k)!},$$
which is 
$$(1+x)^\beta(1-x)^\alpha=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k}p_k(\alpha)p_{n-k}(\beta).\tag{1}$$
I leave the details of your specific case to you.

---

As we may recognize, $$p_n(\alpha)=(-1)^n(-\alpha)_n=(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)},$$
so $(1)$ corresponds quite closely to the identity $$(a+b)_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(a)_k(b)_{n-k}$$
which comes from the fact that $(1-x)^{-a}(1-x)^{-b}=(1-x)^{-(a+b)}$ and $$(1-x)^{-s}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(s)_n}{n!}x^n=\,_1F_0(s;;x).$$

Answer (score 0):

So I think you want to expand the expression?
$$
(1+x)^{n-m}(1-x)^m
= \sum_{i=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{i} x^i \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{m}{j}(-x)^j
= \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{l=\max(0,k-n+m)}^{\min(k,m)} \binom{n-m}{k-l}\binom{m}{l} x^{k-l}(-x)^{l}
$$
$$
= \sum_{k=0}^n x^k \sum_{l=\max(0,k-n+m)}^{\min(k,m)} (-1)^l\binom{n-m}{k-l}\binom{m}{l}
$$
I'm not sure how to simplify the last sum with the binomial coefficients, but this is a power series expansion.

Answer (score 0):

*More than likely, too complex.*

Using what has been given in previous answers
$$f(n,m)=(1+x)^{n-m}(1-x)^{m}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty a_p\, x^p$$ where
$$a_p=\binom{n-m}{p} \, _2F_1(-m,-p;n-m-p+1;-1)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.